# Related to ArrayList And Hashtable

Tags: java

I have created one Hashtable and an arraylist.In arrayList I have values from which some are present in hashtable as key of hashtable. I am trying to check how many entry of elements stored in arraylist are there in Hashtable.

Comment: What's the question? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far for trying

Answer (score 2):

Short, lazy question, short, lazy answer:

Use a loop over your list, count how many trues you get:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Uparrow for answer's first line